# Почему в WeakMap value не удаляется, когда выводишь всю коллекцию, но удаляется, когда при выводе одного эл-та?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Везде пишется про ключ WeakMap:

1. Ключом в этой структуре данных может быть только объект
2. WeakMap не может держать ссылку на ключ-объект. При удалении ключа-объекта значение тоже удалится.

НО что насчет `value`? Почему в этом случае даже при "обнулении" элемент все равно выводится?

```
let weakMap = new WeakMap();
let obj = {name: 'Ivan'};
//добавление нового элемента
weakMap.set({}, obj);
obj = null;
console.log(weakMap);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот тут уже не выводится. В чем причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Точно такая же ситуация с `key`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Все довольно просто, когда вы добавляете элемент в строке

```js
weakMap.set({}, obj);
```

Вы создаете новый(!!!) ключ-объект `{}`, а потом в строке

```js
obj = null;
```

вы "удаляете" даже не сам ключ, а его значение т.е `value`.

Чтобы удалить элемент из `WeakMap`, воспользуйтесь методом `delete(key)`.

Если я правильно вас понял, то должно получиться что-то такое:

```js
let weakMap = new WeakMap();
let obj = {name: 'Ivan'};
let key = {}; // создаем объект с возможностью сослаться на него

//добавление нового элемента
weakMap.set(key, obj); // если вместо key будет {} мы не сможем получить на этот объект ссылку

console.log(weakMap); // weakMap с 1 элементом

weakMap.delete(key); // ссылка на ключ в качестве аргумента, если мы снова вместо key будем использовать {}, то ничего не выйдет, т.к если помните {} != {}
key = null; // это уже даже не нужно будет, т.е сборщик заметит, что ссылок на эту переменную нигде нет и удалит из памяти
obj = null; // это тоже не имеет смысла в контексте данного вопроса, т.к используется в качестве значения

console.log(weakMap); // weakMap пуст
```

Надеюсь, что я сам где-нибудь не ошибся в нюансах, если что, меня поправят.